# BorderLayout problem with JSplitPane after adding JToolbar (Java)

Tags: java, swing, layout, jsplitpane, jtoolbar

Problem:

My program layout is fine, as below before I add JToolbar to `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`
Here's a screenshot before JToolbar is added:
[image]

Here's how it looked like after adding JToolbar:
[image]

May I know what did I do wrong?

Here's the code I used:

```
    //Create the text pane and configure it.
    textPane = new JTextPane();
    -snipped code-
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

    //Create the text area for the status log and configure it.
    changeLog = new JTextArea(5, 30);
    changeLog.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPaneForLog = new JScrollPane(changeLog);

    //Create a split pane for the change log and the text area.
    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(
            JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
            scrollPane, scrollPaneForLog);
    splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);

    //Create the status area.
    JPanel statusPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    CaretListenerLabel caretListenerLabel =
            new CaretListenerLabel("Caret Status");
    statusPane.add(caretListenerLabel);

    //Create the toolbar
    JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
    -snipped code-

    //Add the components.
    getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(statusPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    //Set up the menu bar.
    actions = createActionTable(textPane);
    JMenu editMenu = createEditMenu();
    JMenu styleMenu = createStyleMenu();
    JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
    mb.add(editMenu);
    mb.add(styleMenu);
    setJMenuBar(mb);
```

Please help, I'm new to GUI Building, and I don't feel like using Netbeans to drag and drop the UI for me... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `setSize()` on the `JFrame`, set the preferred size of your center component as you do now and invoke [`pack()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack(%29), which "Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents." Expanding on @Bragaadeesh's example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.build();
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Then, change to `scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300))` or `JTextArea changeLog = new JTextArea(10, 30)` to see the difference.

Comment: @trashgod: Oh! So that's how it's supposed to be. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is the issue. I tried to run it on my system by fixing the compilation issues. Here is the code and screenshot.

[image: test frame]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFrame frame = new TestFrame();
        frame.build();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void build(){
        setSize(600,600);
        //Create the text pane and configure it.
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        //Create the text area for the status log and configure it.
        JTextArea changeLog = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        changeLog.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPaneForLog = new JScrollPane(changeLog);

        //Create a split pane for the change log and the text area.
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(
                JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                scrollPane, scrollPaneForLog);
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);

        //Create the status area.
        JPanel statusPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        JLabel caretListenerLabel =
                new JLabel("Caret Status");
        statusPane.add(caretListenerLabel);

        //Create the toolbar
        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Btn1"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Btn2"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Btn3"));
        toolBar.add(new JButton("Btn4"));

        //Add the components.
        getContentPane().add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(statusPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //Set up the menu bar.
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("test");
        JMenu styleMenu = new JMenu("test");
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        mb.add(editMenu);
        mb.add(styleMenu);
        setJMenuBar(mb);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Bragaadeesh: Okay... that is weird. I'll try to copy paste the one you used and test and see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I understand why now.

I used Paint to give me a rough estimation of the pixels, and previously I did not know that the height from the start of the top frame title bar is counted! So that adds up to ~= 504. I get it now.

So next time when I have to set the height roughly, I think I'll use Paint.

[image]

---

Hmmm weird. I have to change from:

```
//Display the window.
frame.setSize(640, 480);
```

to

```
//Display the window.
frame.setSize(640, 504);
```

Then only it works.

Can somebody teach me how to estimate or set the width/height for the components? Because initially I wanted it to be `640,480` but apparently now it needs `640,504`.